# ngModel with dynamic variable

Tags: angular, typescript, ngmodel

I am facing some problem when use `ngModel` to emit value to bump object with property get from `bumpDetail.name` array.

I have pasted my code snippet down below. 
 Could anyone please help me by checking it and tell me where I have done wrong? Thank you.

```
<p *ngFor="let bumpDetail of bumpDetail">
    <input type="checkbox" id="device" [(ngModel)]={{bump.bumpDetail.name}}/>
    <label for="device">{{bumpDetail.name}}</label>
</p>
```

```
 Bump[] = [{
"name": "bump_1",
"status": true
}, {
"name": "bump_2",
"status": false
 }, {
"name": "bump_3",
"status": true
}]
```

This is error.

> Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{bumpDetail.name}}] in ng:///AppModule/SettingComponent.html@129:59 ("p *ngFor="let bumpDetail of bumpDetail">

Comment: What is the expected behavior? What doesn't work? Do you get an error message? What part is variable and what values can it contain?

Comment: I had edit my post. Could you help me check it ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`[]` and `{{}}` are **never** used together. Either one or the other

```
[(ngModel)]="this[bumpDetail.name]"
```

`{{}}` is for string interpolation only.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in `[(ngModel)]={{bumpDetail.name}}`

It should be: `[(ngModel)]="bumpDetail.status"`

You don't need `{{}}` when using `[(ngModel)]` or any other ng-directive for that matter.

Secondly i think there might be something wrong here `<p *ngFor="let bumpDetail of bumpDetail">` verify that the name of your variable is correct, and these 2 can't be the same.

I would change it to this: `<p *ngFor="let bumpDetail of bumpDetailArray">` where `bumpDetailArray` is the array

Comment: Are you getting the same error? or different error?

Comment: Problem still occur.

Answer (score 0):

Get the basics right first {{}} is an expression and [(ngModel)] is for two way binding where () is emitting and [] is for binding.What you need to do is like `[(ngModel)]="bumpDetail.name"` and if you want to print it then you need to use the expression like `{{bumpDetail.name}}`. You cannot use both of them together like you have used above.

Comment: Sorry, i had edit my post. I want to use ngModel to emit value to bump object with property get from bumpDetail.name array.